# Should I store a value for every damage type even if zero, when using the Decorator pattern?

Tags: architecture, design-patterns

My game characters take damage by the method `TakeDamage(Damage amounts)`, and the `Damage` struct has every type of damage (`fireDamage`, `iceDamage`, `bluntDamage`, etc.).  For now every `Weapon` has a lot of info in the `Damage` struct that isn't used, e.g. the common `Hammer` just has `bluntDamage`; and the others (`fireDamage`, `edgeDamage`, etc.) are all zero.

Is this the correct way, or should I use the Decorator Pattern for every kind of damage instead?  Or is there another way?

Answer (score 7):

As a general rule, one should never be a slave to any pattern.  Be flexible.  As for the particular example you give, it's a rather well known case, so I can help a bit with the pros and cons.  I can say outright that it *has* been done both ways.

- **Who is going to read your code?**  This should be your number one concern.  As Gudio von Rossum put it, "Code is read more often than it is written."  The decorator pattern is not the most complicated design pattern out there, but it is a design pattern.  It provides a great deal of flexibility, so any developer working on the code is going to have to be thinking of this flexibility while they work on it.  The brute force approach is not as flexible, so it's easier to wrap your brain around it.
- **Understand your costs.**  How big of a deal is it that every weapon has a few extra bytes of data on it?  Most of the time, it's not so bad.  How big of a deal is it to add a new damage type?  If you build your class structure well, it may be easy.  If you do it poorly, you may find that you have to wade through the code to find all the loops that use the damage types and add to them.  Also know that the typical decorator pattern requires heap allocations.  For a game, that may be very affordable, but if you have a strategy engine that has to generate millions of these weapons every second to make decisions, that could hurt.
- How many types of damage do you have? Are there 8 types? 50 types?  Can the user create new types?  The more types you have to deal with, the more "waste" there is in the brute force solution.
- How many permutations are there for different damage types?  Can you have an ice/fire/poisoned/blunt/sharp-thing that does all those types of damage?  If you know that none of your weapons are going to do more than 4 types of damage, you can create an array of 4 "slots," each of which holds a damage type and a damage amount.  You could also use a `std::vector` if you wanted an unbounded number of types.

  - Why use this over Decorator? Pros and cons.  This approach provides flexibility, but with some restriction.  Decorator opens the door wide for any modification of any Weapon behavior, while this approach sets some ground rules for what sorts of patterns are permitted.  Look at your code, think of your readers, and find the best balance.
- Know that, if you use Decorator, you will need to develop a damage API that is robust enough to handle any arbitrary behavior a decorator may wish to use.  This API may not be as readable as a simple one which scans through a table and sums up damage.

Answer (score 3):

There is never just one correct way in programming. Any solution which gives you correct results is a "correct" solution. But not every "correct" solution is also a "good" solution. However, which solutions are good and which are bad usually depends on your unique requirements and personal preferences.

Some possible solutions:

- When you have a large amount of damage types but all damage sources are just going to have one kind of damage, you only need two fields in your damage structure: `value` and `type`.
- When you have some damage sources which do mixed damage but very few which use all the available damage types, you could use an array of damage-structures.
- You could also go the object-oriented way. Make `Damage` an interface with a public method `applyTo(victim)`. You can then have multiple classes which implement that interface in different ways. For example, the applyTo method of class `SimpleDamage` could have one value and one type, the class `PoisonEffectDamage` could not affect the victims's hit points but would instead put a poison effect on it, the class `CompositeDamage` could be an aggregate of multiple `Damage` objects which are applied one after another while `MultiformDamage` could have only one value but multiple types and uses the worst (or best? or average? or sum?) of the resistances of the victim.